# Magento before install on centos 7 getting 500 internal server error

Tags: magento, installation, centos7

Hi I am trying to install magento 1.9.x and magento2 in my centos operating system.. the following links help to configure apache2.4, php7 and mysql5.7 in centos.

[Install magento link](https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/install-magento-2-community-edition-on-centos-7/)

after configure web server, php, mysql, magento files and all. I create database for magento2. Based on above link i did all steps one-by-one. After i run in browser localhost/magento2/

it show 500 Internal server error in firebug  and blank browser.

I am beginner of centos and magento

Please any one help how to solve this problem i was spend past two days.

Apache error log:

> [Sat Sep 10 14:22:33.728848 2016] [:error] [pid 2809] [client
>   ::1:45432] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir
>   "/var/www/html/magento2/var/page_cache" is not writable in
>   /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library‌​/Zend/Cache.php:209\‌​nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library‌​/Zend/Cache/Backend/‌​File.php(180):
>   Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "/var...')\n#1
>   /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-‌​file/File.php(87):
>
> Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/var/www/html/m...')\n‌​#2
>   /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library‌​/Zend/Cache.php(153)‌​:
>   Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array)\n#3
>   /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library‌​/Zend/Cache.php(94):
>   Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true)\n#4
>
> /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Ca‌​che/Frontend/Factory‌​.php(158):
>   Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...',
>   Array, Array, true, true, true)\n#5
>   /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Ca‌​che/Frontend
>   in
>   /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library‌​/Zend/Cache.php
>   on line 209

Comment: The error is related to Apache and It is impossible to know without looking at the Apache logs. Refresh the page `http://localhost/magento2/, check the /var/log folder and search for the Apache logs. Also this question would be more meaningful in ServerFault instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: @Marcs I check in var/log directory.. i found httpd folder inside i saw access_log file it contains following error
::1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:12:05 +0530] "GET /magento2/ HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"....

Comment: You need to check the error_log, check the docs about error logging on the apache docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html

Comment: [Sat Sep 10 14:22:33.728848 2016] [:error] [pid 2809] [client ::1:45432] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/var/www/html/magento2/var/page_cache" is not writable in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(180): Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "/var...')\n#1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(87):

Comment: Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/var/www/html/m...')\n#2 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array)\n#3 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true)\n#4

Comment: /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(158): Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\\\\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, Array, true, true, true)\n#5 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Cache/Frontend in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php on line 209

Comment: this above three commands as error in error_log file... @Marcs will u pls help me what can i do now....

Comment: Please update your question with the error log don't cram up the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

To me this look like the main problem:

> Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir
>   **"/var/www/html/magento2/var/page_cache" is not writable** in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library‌​/Zend/Cache.php:209\‌​nStack

You have the wrong permissions or wrong owner for this folder. You can fix this using `chown` for fixing the owner of that folder or `chmod` for fixing writing permissions for that folder.

Try this:

`chown -R apache.apache /var/www/html/magento2/`

This sets the whole magento2 folder to have apache as owner and group. It is not the best security measure but for testing is fine.

Comment: I use to change owner and file permissions even though I'm getting same error

Comment: If you get still the same error in the error_log then you still need to fix permissions/owner for that cache folder. Your best shot is to set the owner to `apache.apache` if this is the correct user for centos (http://serverfault.com/questions/416236/what-is-centos-5s-apache-user-group).

In case the error changed, I recommend you to check error_log and search for infos online, installation problems like this are often quite documented.